# How to use .map in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Pig Latin

Rule 1: If a word begins with a vowel sound, add an "ay" sound to
the end of the word.

Rule 2: If a word begins with a consonant sound, move it to the end
of the word, and then add an "ay" sound to the end of the word.

The following program works in ruby. But I'm confused on how to use the "map" function? Please see the code as follows:

```
def translate(sentence)
  if sentence.include?(" ")
    words = sentence.split(" ").map do |word|       
      translate_word(word)                        
    end
    return  words.join(" ")
  else single_word = sentence
    translate_word(single_word)
  end
end
```

The above sentences works! but if I use:

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
words.map do |word|
  translate_word(word)
end
```

It DOESN'T work! Why? I thought they were the same...

```
def translate_word(w)
  vowels = %w[a e i o u]
  consonants = ("a".."z").to_a - vowels 

  if vowels.include?(w[0])
    w + "ay"
    elsif consonants.include?(w[0]) && vowels.include?(w[1]) && w[1] != "u"
      w[1..-1] + w[0] + "ay"
    elsif (consonants.include?(w[0]) && consonants.include?(w[1]) && vowels.include?(w[2]) && w[2] != "u") || (w[0] == "q" && w[1] == "u")
      w[2..-1] + w[0..1] + "ay"
    elsif (consonants.include?(w[0]) && consonants.include?(w[1]) && consonants.include?(w[2]) && vowels.include?(w[3])) 
      w[3..-1] + w[0..2] + "ay"
    elsif consonants.include?(w[0]) && w[1] == "q" && w[2] == "u"
      w[3..-1] + w[0..2] + "ay"
    end
end
```

Comment: where do u want to use map?

Comment: Note that your question doesn't drill down to what you're trying to map and what problems you're running into. This is a good reference for improving your question: http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

`#map` function returns a new object which you are dismissing.
To save the result you should assign it back to `words` like this:

```
words = sentence.split(" ")
words = words.map do |word| 
  translate_word(word)
end
```

Or use `#map!` instead.